# Add Form Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I work with symfony2: I have 3 entities Piece, Brand and model. When adding a piece I must indicate the make and model.
When I do the CRUD, everything works, it shows me all the brands and models. except that I want when I choose the brand it shows me only models related to this brand.

```
class Piece {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="refference", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $refference;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ref1", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ref1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ref2", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ref2;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ref3", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ref3;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Modele", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $modele;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Localisation", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $localisation;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set refference
     *
     * @param string $refference
     * @return Piece
     */
    public function setRefference($refference)
    {
        $this->refference = $refference;

        return $this;
    }

    function getModele() {
        return $this->modele;
    }

    function setModele($modele) {
        $this->modele = $modele;
    }

    function getLocalisation() {
        return $this->localisation;
    }

    function setLocalisation($localisation) {
        $this->localisation = $localisation;
    }

    function getMar() {
        $m=new Marque();
        return $m->getNom();
    }



    /**
     * Get refference
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRefference()
    {
        return $this->refference;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Piece
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set ref1
     *
     * @param string $ref1
     * @return Piece
     */
    public function setRef1($ref1)
    {
        $this->ref1 = $ref1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ref1
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRef1()
    {
        return $this->ref1;
    }

    /**
     * Set ref2
     *
     * @param string $ref2
     * @return Piece
     */
    public function setRef2($ref2)
    {
        $this->ref2 = $ref2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ref2
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRef2()
    {
        return $this->ref2;
    }

    /**
     * Set ref3
     *
     * @param string $ref3
     * @return Piece
     */
    public function setRef3($ref3)
    {
        $this->ref3 = $ref3;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ref3
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRef3()
    {
        return $this->ref3;
    }
}
```

**PieceType.php**

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('refference')
                ->add('description')
                ->add('localisation')
                ->add('ref1')
                ->add('ref2')
                ->add('ref3')
                ->add('marque')
                ->add('modele');
    }
```

[Example of my add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIkpi.png)

suggest please?

Comment: use ajax to change `model` field values when `brand` value is changed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use AJAX, you can use the `CraueFormFlowBundle` to create a `FormType` with different steps and make some rules in `symfony`.

Comment: Thx , i will try it